# Errors when using SMTPLIB SSL email with a 365 email address

Tags: python, email, ssl, office365, smtplib

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.office365.com", 587, context=context) as server:
```

(587) When I run this I get an SSL error: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056).

(465) I get a timeout error.

I tried using ports 465 and 587. I get different errors when I use different ports. I did try 995 just for the heck of it and still no luck. If I use my gmail account, I have no issues.

Is there something I need to do to my email account so it works. I also tried .SMTP() and still no luck.

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587)
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtp.starttls(context=context) as server:
    server.login(from_address, password)

    for i, r in newhire[mask].iterrows():     
            server.sendmail(
                from_address,
                r["Email"],
                message.format(Employee=r["Employee Name"],
                   StartDate=r["StartDate"],
                               PC=r["PC"],
                               Title=r["Title"],
                               Email=r["Email"], 


                )
            )
```

Comment: can you add your full code respect to send email??

Comment: The "version" probably refers to the version of the SSL cipher. What SSL version does the server offer to you? It's not entirely uncommon for Exchange servers to run software which should never have been written in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation of SMTP_SSL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL):

> SMTP_SSL should be used for situations where SSL is required from the beginning of the connection and using starttls() is not appropriate.

Thus, SMTP_SSL is for implicit SMTP and the common port for this is 465. Port 587 is instead used for explicit SMTP where a plain connect is done and later an upgrade to SSL with the STARTTLS command.

What happens here is that the client tries to speak SSL/TLS to a server which does not expect SSL/TLS at this stage and thus replies with non-TLS data. These get interpreted as TlS nonetheless which results in this strange `[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]`.

To fix this either use port 465 (and not 587) with SMTP_SSL (not supported by Office365)  or use port 587 but with [starttls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls):

```
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587) as server:
     server.starttls(context=context)
```

Comment: should the context still be  equaled to ssl.create_default_context()? I get a AttributeError: __enter__ when I run this. smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587)
 context = ssl.create_default_context() with smtp.starttls(context=context) as server:  server.login(from_address, password)

Comment: @RobertoGonzalez: `starttls` does not return a server. It should be `with smtplib.SMTP... ` instead of `with smtplib.SMTP_SSL ...`  and then later `server.starttls(...)`.

Comment: I posted what I am running now above. I believe I do have it the way you suggested but please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @RobertoGonzalez: `with smtp.starttls(context=context) as server:`  - this is wrong. Please see my last comment and the edited answer.