# How do I set the SSL protocol needed for ActionMailer to use a TLS connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, actionmailer

I am running into an issue trying to use my campus's SMTP server with my Rails 5.x app. I receive the following error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol.

Here is my configuration:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'address.domain',
    port:                 587,
    user_name:            'UNAME',
    password:             'PWD',
    authentication:       :login,
    tls:                  true,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

To ensure I am using the latest openssl version, I have also required 'openssl' in my Gemfile, and it installed openssl-2.1.2.

Suggestions on next steps?

Comment: I have been informed it needs to be TLSv1.2 or 1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
port:                 587,
...
tls:                  true,
enable_starttls_auto: true
```

According to [the documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) *":ssl/:tls - Enables the SMTP connection to use SMTP/TLS (SMTPS: SMTP over **direct** TLS connection)"*. But port 587 is not for direct TLS but for TLS upgrade via the STARTTLS command. Direct TLS is done on port 465 instead if enabled.

Thus, your client tries to access a non-TLS connection with TLS and this results in this strange error. See also [my explanation on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59635739/3081018) where this happened with Perl not Ruby.

To solve the problem either use port 465 with `tls` (if enabled on the server) or use port 587 and rely on `enable_starttls_auto` that it will do a later upgrade to TLS.

Comment: Removing tls: true fixed it up like a charm! Thank you so much!.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing some things with Rails and email right now and was disturbed by the lack of description in docs about a way to require STARTTLS. Without making it a requirement, it is almost as not having that at all IMO.

So I checked in the sources. Since at least Ruby 2.4, enforcing STARTTLS is [supported](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/lib/net/smtp.rb#L333).

It seems that it can be enabled in rails in the same way `enable_starttls_auto` is enabled, just set `enable_starttls` instead. It is not documented but it seems like all settings are just passed down to `Mail::SMTP` so hwatever it supports can be passed.

Update: Rails project accepted my documentation update [#44096](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/44096).